# angular directive template stopped working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I was using angular directive and it was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working and i don't know why. Here is my code:

```
<div id="main" data-ng-controller="Controller" data-ng-app="app">
 <div class="stars">
  <star-rating value="{{item.Value.Rate}}"></star-rating>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My angular code is here:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('starRating', function () {

```
return {

    scope: {
        value: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="stars"><i class="fa fa-star" ng-repeat="r in entries"></i></div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.entries = _.range($scope.value);
    }

}
```

});

```
   app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
        //
    })
.config(function ($httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; 
     charset=utf-8";
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
         });
```

i really don't know what i'm missing.

Comment: var app = angular.module('app', []); app.directive('starRating', function () {
Change to 
var app = angular.module('app'); app.directive('starRating', function () {

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Than I need more code... Did you include code with directive into the page?

Comment: What did you change immediately before it suddenly stopped working? That's probably a good place to look :)

Comment: what do you mean include? my script codes is seperate and i referance it to the page

Comment: @iblamefish i actually did not change anything, that is the main problem :) is it about version or something? should i update my codes? because i made this long time ago.

Comment: @user3188649 so it sounds like the thing you changed immediately before it stopped working is the version of Angular. Is that correct? From which version to which version?

Comment: @iblamefish i'm using v1.2.32. i solved the problem with ng-repeat. i don't use template :/